# Failed to link folder names to their *.html contents

Tags: html, perl

Here is my code and folder.

#### Folder structure:

```
Mus
|-- Mus.config
|-- Mus.html
`-- Mus_Digital
    |-- Digi_Verification
    |   |-- Digi_Verification.config
    |   |-- Digi_Verification.html
    |   `-- rev1
    |       |-- _projects_Mus_Mus_Digi_Digi_Verification_rev1.config
    |       `-- _projects_Mus_Mus_Digi_Digi_Verification_rev1.html
    |-- Mus_Digital.config
    `-- Mus_Digital.html
```

The above is my obtained directory structure from `$output_dir`. I need to convert all  `.config` files to `.html` format.

If I click the `Mus` folder it should open `Mus.html`, if I click `Mus_Digital` it should open `Mus_Digital.html`, and so on. The same should apply to all folders and sub folders and also for `href` links.

In my code the `href` links are not pointing to its *.html. Help to point directly to its `*.html` file when the folder is clicked.

#### My code:

```perl
print "Converting the .config files to .html files at destination location \n";

##HTML CONVERSION##

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->name( '*.config' )->prune->in( $output_dir );

foreach my $file ( @files ) {

    my ( $name, $root, $ext ) = $file =~ m|(.*)/(.*)\.(.*)|;

    my $outfile = "$name/$root.html";
    open my $fh_out, '>', $outfile or die "Can't open $outfile: $!", "\n";

    my $head = "
<!doctype html>
<html lang=\"en\"> 
  <head>
    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">
    <title>DCMS_CHECKLIST</title>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </head> 
  <body>
    <table>
      <th>SL.NO</th>
      <th>CHECKLIST ITEM</th>
      <th>VALUE</th>
      <th>COMMENTS</th>
      <th>CONFIRMATION</th>
      <style>
        .bold {
          font-weight: bold;
        }
        .bold td
        {
        border: 0px;
        }
        table, th, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
      </style>";

    print $fh_out $head;    # write the header

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
    
    while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {

        chomp $line;

        for ( $line ) {
            s/\&//g;
            #s/[\\\_\@\_]//g;
            s/COMMENT//g;
        }

        my @data  = split /:/, $line;
        my $class = $data[0] ? 'normal' : 'bold';

        print $fh_out qq[<tr class="$class">];

        # my $href="http://iad.sd.aog.com/cps/dev/kb/cms/cms_prects/";

        my $check  = 0;
        my $dolink = $data[0] !~ m/[\=\%]/;

        for my $word ( @data ) {

            $check++;

            print $fh_out '<td>';

            if ( $check == 1 && $dolink ) {
                print $fh_out '<a href="'$word'.html">' . $word . '</a>';   
            }
            else {
                print $fh_out $word;
            }

            print $fh_out '</td>';
        }
    }
}
```

`$href` is the default output directory. All the output directories will be under this path.

**Expected part in the code is as follows:**

Each .html file will have some contents with the href link.Those contents names are named with folder names.

so,now if i click any of those links it should open the respected directories .html file.

For example:

Mus.html have the following contents .

Tensil

chip

Mus_Digital

Each row contents will have href link.So if i click Mus_Digital it should directly open the Mus_Digital.html.Inside Mus_Digital.html i have some other contents with href link(i.e Digi_verification Now if i click Digi verification it should open Digi_verification.html).Now it fails to open as i mentioned.

**Re-consider:**

1.Here you can able to see many .html files from parent folder and sub folders.

2.So now if you open any one .html file you can view the folder names(such as Mus_Digital,Digi_verification,rev1)

3.So now you can see the folder structure here Mus_Digital directly link to Mus_Digital.html,Digi_Verification directly link to Digi_Verification.html,rev1 directly link to _Projects_Mus_Mus_Digi_Digi_Verfication_rev1.html.

4.Likewise now if you click any of the folder names which have href links it should open the linking .html file)

For example consider Now you are inside the Mus.html.Here you have the following contents like Mus_Digital and Digi_Verification.If you click Mus_Digital it should open Mus_Digital.html .(For your reference you can check the folder structure).

**sample output:**

I had done this in termial:

```
firefox file:///_projects/Mus/

Name    Size    Last Modified
Muska.config 1 KB   04/12/2017  02:26:57 PM
Muska.html   1 KB   04/12/2017  02:27:00 PM
Muska_Digital           04/12/2017  02:27:00 PM
```

Now i click Muska.html it have the following contents with links

```
SL.NO   CHECKLIST ITEM  VALUE   COMMENTS    CONFIRMATION
Tensilica   0%  0%
ChipTop     0%  0%
Mus_Digital     100.00%     100.00%
OVERALL_STATUS=33.33%
PARTIAL_STATUS=33.33%
```

Now if click Mus_Digital from the above it shows the following error:

```
File not found

Firefox can't find the file at /_projects/Muska/Mus_Digital .html.

    Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors.
    Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.

Suppose if i click Mus_Digital folder from here firefox file:///_projects/Mus/

I will open the following contents:

Name    Size    Last Modified
Digi_Verification 04/12/2017    02:27:00 PM
File:Muska_Digital.config 1 KB  04/12/2017  02:26:57 PM
File:Muska_Digital.html 1 KB    04/12/2017  02:27:00 PM

Here if i click Digi_verification it will open the following file with contents.

Name    Size    Last Modified
File:Digi_Verification.config
    1 KB    04/12/2017  02:26:56 PM
File:Digi_Verification.html
    1 KB    04/12/2017  02:27:00 PM
rev1
        04/12/2017  02:27:00 PM
```

Here if i click Digi_verification.html it will open the following contents:

```
SL.NO   CHECKLIST ITEM  VALUE   COMMENTS    CONFIRMATION
Revision1   100.00%     100.00%
OVERALL_STATUS=100.00%
PARTIAL_STATUS=100.00%
```

If i click Revision1 it shows following error;

```
File not found

Firefox can't find the file at /_projects/Mus/Mus_Digital/Digi_Verification/Revision1 .html.

    Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors.
    Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.
```

Expected output:

```
Links are broken and they are fetching from its right folder location
```

Comment: You've updated the crucial line `print $fh_out '<a href="' .html '">' . $word . '</a>'` a couple of times and now the code doesn't compile under strictures. Please can you make it match the code you're having trouble with? And make sure that you have `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` in place.

Comment: Is this CGI code?

Comment: @Borodin: I don't it's CGI code - I think it's generating static HTML files.

Comment: @DaveCross: That's what it's *doing*, but people's write some strange stuff expecting it to appear on their browser! Also, they talk about *"If I click the `Mus` folder it should open `Mus.html`"* and I don't think they're talking about a file explorer.

Comment: Here my .html files contains contents with href links.Each href links points to directory and sub directory names.If i click href links(i.e links with directory names should point to the respected .html files from its represented directory names).Finally the links should open the represented .html files.@Borodin

Comment: i had added my expected part queries in my question check with it let me know for any doubts@Borodin

Comment: @gore: Your edit didn't clarify anything at all. Please give us some sample inputs along with the expected output.

Comment: check now@DaveCross

Comment: @gore: Do you not understand what I mean when I ask you to show us the expected output? As I understand it, the output you want is HTML, but the samples you've edited into your question are plain text. Where are the HTML tags? Exactly what output do you need?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve here, it's quite an old programming style you are using but is it as simple as changing the printing of the link?

```
print $fh_out '<a href="' .html '">' . $word . '</a>';
```

to

```
print $fh_out '<a href="' . $word . '.html">' . $word . '</a>';
```

Comment: Or, even, just `print $fh_out qq[<a href="$word.html">$word</a>];`.

Comment: But the method which you showed is not linking its html file for its sub directories @Adam Taylor

Comment: @gore: If the answer doesn't do what you want it to do, that will because (even after your recent edits) your question is very unclear.

Comment: @gore: As I said in a comment on the original question. You need to give us some sample input and the expected output. You haven't done that - and that makes it hard for us to help you.

Comment: check now@DaveCross